# Business Central Identifying Object form vs Extension Form

Tags: dynamics-business-central

I'm also one of many who has begun development work in Business Central. I'm currently in-charge of migrating C/SIDE to AL. My question is, is there a way to identify whether something is in Object form or Extension form? The documentation I have from a third-party vendor says:

"All of company XYZ's products are available in both Object form and in Extension form. Existing customers who want to migrate from the Object version of a solution to the App version will need to go through a migration...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a little clarification:

- Object form means that the modifications have been done through C/Side.
- Extension form means that the modifications are isolated within their own package with one or more dependencies to other extensions. These are not visible in the C/Side Object Designer.

When modifications are done through C/Side the system generates symbols to simulate the extension interface. This provides the needed features to extend C/Side objects.

The easiest way to determine if a modification is in Object or Extension form is to check which extensions are installed on the system. This is can be done in two ways:

1. In the Business Central client go the the Extension Mangement page. Here all installed extensions will be listed (apart from a few hidden Microsoft extensions that you need not worry about).
2. Run the command [`Get-NAVAppInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.dynamics.nav.apps.management/get-navappinfo?view=businesscentral-ps-18) through PowerShell. This will list all installed extensions on the requested tenant.

Comment: Thank you very much for the additional clarification. It helps a lot. So, it sounds like from the company documentation I received, I need to determine which form is being utilized.